# Google map info window on wrong locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm following this code for Multiple Markers in Google map, my problem is once I put my data in the map their info window are all in the wrong coordinates, they seem scrambled. I am using US as my center. So here is the code below:

```
var locations = [
    ['Russ Martin</br>Montana',43.299428,-74.217933],
    ['Carey Fischer</br>New York',46.879682,-110.362566],
    ['Brandon Born</br>Connecticut',40.714353,-74.005973],
    ['Joe Tocyloski</br>Pennysylvania',41.603221,-73.087749]
];

var us  = new google.maps.LatLng(42.746632,-75.770041);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: us,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        /*icon:{
          strokeColor:'green',
          scale:3
        },*/
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.close(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
    console.log(locations);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/eaeS8/)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: And some notes as to where the markers are appearing and where they're _meant_ to appear.

Comment: This is ok for me with proper init function.

Comment: This works fine. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Yeah its working now I have no idea but why does it look like it needs to have 4 array entries to work? Try deleting one.

Comment: Viewing the code, I assume that your problem is showing the Info Window, Right?, You are using wrong the anonymous function.

Comment: Yup the Info Window, I haven't realized that. hmm how is my anonymous function wrong?

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JV4v/). What is the issue?

Comment: info window for markers are not correct

Comment: What do you mean by that?  They are where the code is putting them (Russ is north of Brandon, Carey  is to the west and off screen initially).  What do you expect that is different from that?

Comment: ok the updated code is in the fiddle but I'll update the code here as well

Comment: The text state names in your fiddle are not consistent with the coordinates you are using.

Comment: So looking at the code Russ should be on Minnesota and Carey should be in New York But its the other way around.

Comment: You have it hard coded that way. Fix the coordinates in your code.  Those are wrong, where did they come from?

Comment: I've checked google maps pretty sure I have the right coordinates for Minnesota

Comment: oops typo it should be Montana

Comment: @wrivas could you elaborate what you mean by wrong anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

**below statement may** 
this will surely help u

```
return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        }
```

Comment: Why would you use parseInt on a floating point number? (the coordinates are floats, truncating them to integers will definitely put them in the wrong place.